# what does "Aggregate the data to weekly level, so that there is one row per product-week combination" mean and how can I do it using python (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, data-science

I am working on a transactions data frame using python (anaconda) and I was told to Aggregate the data to a weekly level so that there is one row per product-week combination
I want to make sure if the following code is correct because I don't think I fully understood what I need to do

```
dataset.groupby(['id', dataset['history_date'].dt.strftime('%W')])['sales'].sum()
```

Note my dataset contains the following:

```
id history_date item_id price inventory sales category_id
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s clearly an education question where the asker hasn’t invested time to try to solve it.  There is no explanation of what they’ve tried and no sample data is provided.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :).  You should open a new question after attempting to solve it.  Include some sample data and an explanation of where you failed after trying.

Comment: thank you John. As you can see the question is confusing: the " one row per product-week combination" part is what I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Aggregating data means combining datasets based on a certain criteria, to narrow it down.

For example, it sounds like your dataset may be broken down by daily dates, where each row corresponds to a specific date.

What you need to do is aggregate the data into weekly segments, instead of having it broken down on a daily basis.

This is achieved by grouping your datasets based on the date & the most granular / detailed /specific pairing of your dataset.

Comment: so the "one row per product-week combination" means that the dataset needs to be  grouped by week and by product?

Comment: Yeah, think about it. if your data is broken down by daily, 11/01, 11/02, 11/03, if you want to aggregate the data to a weekly segment, your dataset needs to show something like 11/01, 11/08, etc.

Comment: therefore my code should be : dataset.groupby(['id', dataset['history_date'].dt.strftime('%W')])  ?

Comment: i don't know, you haven't posted the dataset nor have you posted any code so we have no idea.

Comment: That is fine, you should be able to research on your own now that you understand what type of aggregation is required